# How to formulate reinforcement learning problem with State as a combination of multiple factors?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am reading sutton's `reinforcement learning an introduction`. The book mentioned that for continuous state space, one could leverage value function with the form

`V(s, w) = W*S`,

where `s` represents state and `w` the weights. So if there is only 1 factor in a state, the function could be like, for instance,

`V(s, w) = w_1*s + w_0`

However, what if the state has 2 or more components? Say `S = S(position, time)`, then how to rewrite the above function?

Is it `V(s, w) = w_1*(position + time) + w_0`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Typically each state represented by a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (likewise for actions).

Then one can write $\hat V(s,\theta) = w^Ts + b$ where $s,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Of course this is not really an adequate parameterization of value functions, but just a linear estimator of it.